# About for loops and exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I've been trying to solve problem 11 in project euler.
Basically, what I have to do is, on a number grid of 20 x  20 , I have to find the largest product of the 4 adjacent numbers (left, right, down, up, diagonally).

Here's a Link : http://projecteuler.net/problem=11

Anyways, I have been successful with it (Except it does not finish the while loop), and want your help. I have only learnt java for a while now.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class q11 {

public static void largestProduct() throws FileNotFoundException {

Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("p11.txt")); // Read in numbers from grid file
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
int product = 0;
int i = 0;
boolean retry = false;

while (s.hasNext()) {
  a.add(s.nextInt());
}

while (!retry) {
  try {
    for (i = i; i < a.size(); i++) {
      int origin = a.get(i);

      int lu_diag2 = a.get(i-21);
      int lu_diag3 = a.get(i-21-21);
      int lu_diag4 = a.get(i-21-21-21);
      int luHighest = origin * lu_diag2 * lu_diag3 * lu_diag4;

      int ld_diag2 = a.get(i+19);
      int ld_diag3 = a.get(i+19+19);
      int ld_diag4 = a.get(i+19+19+19);
      int ldHighest = origin * ld_diag2 * ld_diag3 * ld_diag4;

      int ru_diag2 = a.get(i-19);
      int ru_diag3 = a.get(i-19-19);
      int ru_diag4 = a.get(i-19-19-19);
      int ruHighest = origin * ru_diag2 * ru_diag3 * ru_diag4;

      int rd_diag2 = a.get(i+21);
      int rd_diag3 = a.get(i+21+21);
      int rd_diag4 = a.get(i+21+21+21);
      int rdHighest = origin * rd_diag2 * rd_diag3 * rd_diag4;

      int highest = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(rdHighest,ruHighest),ldHighest),luHighest);

      if (highest > product) {
        product = highest;
      }
      if (i == a.size() - 1) {
        retry = true;
      }
    }
  } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    i++;
    continue;
  } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    i++;
    continue;
  }
  System.out.println(product);
}
```

**I do understand** that using exceptions like this is a bad way to program, but I just wanted to try a different approach (Never had the chance at uni).

The problem I'm facing is the infinite loop. The program seems to keep printing the largest product over and over again.

My approach was to increment i whenever an exception occurs, so that exception error will not make the for loop re-set. So, what I've done is declare i above the while loop and in the for loop, wrote 
`for(i = i; i < a.size(); i++)` .

**To summarize:**

1. How can I solve the infinite loop?
2. The for loop required me to assign something, so I've coded i = i. Is this the only way when I've already declared the variable above?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't declare `i` outside of your loop, there's no need.  It's proper to initialize the count variable as part of the loop

Comment: @RhinoFeeder He's doing it because of the using-catch to control program flow madness.

Comment: @Topstar Really, don't do this. It's a horrible idea. Your disclaimer reads like "I know it would really hurt to staple my *(pick an appendage)* to the table, but I want to see what it feels like".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote, using exceptions like that is incorrect. The whole try-catch block is absolutely unnecessary. I don't know whether it is important for you to explain working with arrays and loops. If yes, please reply. For now, I will only provide a solution:

```
public static void largestProduct() throws FileNotFoundException {
Scanner s;
s = new Scanner(new File("p11.txt")); // Read in numbers from grid file
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
int product = 0;

while (s.hasNext()) {
a.add(s.nextInt());
}

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    int origin = a.get(i);
    int luHighest = 0;
    int ldHighest = 0;
    int ruHighest = 0;
    int rdHighest = 0;
    if(i>63){
        int lu_diag2 = a.get(i-21);
        int lu_diag3 = a.get(i-21-21);
        int lu_diag4 = a.get(i-21-21-21);
        luHighest = origin * lu_diag2 * lu_diag3 * lu_diag4;
    }
    if(i<a.size()-57){  
        int ld_diag2 = a.get(i+19);
        int ld_diag3 = a.get(i+19+19);
        int ld_diag4 = a.get(i+19+19+19);
        ldHighest = origin * ld_diag2 * ld_diag3 * ld_diag4;
    }
    if(i>57){ 
        int ru_diag2 = a.get(i-19);
        int ru_diag3 = a.get(i-19-19);
        int ru_diag4 = a.get(i-19-19-19);
        ruHighest = origin * ru_diag2 * ru_diag3 * ru_diag4;
    }
    if(i<a.size()-63){
        int rd_diag2 = a.get(i+21);
        int rd_diag3 = a.get(i+21+21);
        int rd_diag4 = a.get(i+21+21+21);
        rdHighest = origin * rd_diag2 * rd_diag3 * rd_diag4;
    }

    int highest = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(rdHighest,ruHighest),ldHighest),luHighest);

    if (highest > product) {
    product = highest;
    }
}
System.out.println(product);
}
```

I removed try-catch block and added conditions to avoid out of bounds exceptions and also correctly formated the `for` loop, as assignment `i=i` doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't keep iterating the loop when getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception. That exception is yelling at you, "I Don't have more cells to check in here."